# How to get the highest value in a json from an api with python

Tags: python, json

So I am using an api to fetch information. The api returns a json and I am trying to find the highest value number from the key "rating". I am trying to create a discord bot with this information.  The main lines that you should be looking at are

```
for legend in udata['legends']:
    highest_elo = legend.max()
```

And

```
rsemb.add_field(name="Highest Rated Legend", value=f"{highest_elo}", inline=False)

@client.command()
async def rankedstats(ctx, msg):
    id = msg
    url = f"https://api.brawlhalla.com/player/{id}/ranked?api_key=MY_API_KEY"
    r = requests.get(url)
    udata = r.json()
    uname = udata['name']
    upeakrating = udata['peak_rating']
    uwins = udata['wins']
    urating = udata['rating']

    for legend in udata['legends']:
        highest_elo = legend.max()

    rsemb = discord.Embed(title="CurrentElo", colour=3092790)
    rsemb.add_field(name=f"{uname}'s current elo", value=f"{urating}", inline=False)
    rsemb.add_field(name=f"{uname}'s Peak elo",value=f"{upeakrating}", inline=False)
    rsemb.add_field(name=f"{uname}'s ranked wins",value=f"{uwins}", inline=False)
    rsemb.add_field(name="Highest Rated Legend", value=f"{highest_elo}", inline=False)
    rsemb.set_thumbnail(url="https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/306-3068244_brawlhalla-will-slam-into-hd-png-download.png")
   

    await ctx.send(embed=rsemb)
```

When you send a request to the api here is what it returns.

```
{
    "name": "Twitter: ufrz_",
    "brawlhalla_id": 28472387,
    "rating": 2163,
    "peak_rating": 2163,
    "tier": "Diamond",
    "wins": 154,
    "games": 280,
    "region": "US-E",
    "global_rank": 0,
    "region_rank": 0,
    "legends": [
        {
            "legend_id": 3,
            "legend_name_key": "bodvar",
            "rating": 870,
            "peak_rating": 870,
            "tier": "Tin 4",
            "wins": 2,
            "games": 4
        },
        {
            "legend_id": 4,
            "legend_name_key": "cassidy",
            "rating": 968,
            "peak_rating": 968,
            "tier": "Bronze 2",
            "wins": 0,
            "games": 0
        },
        {
            "legend_id": 5,
            "legend_name_key": "orion",
            "rating": 1228,
            "peak_rating": 1228,
            "tier": "Silver 2",
            "wins": 3,
            "games": 5
        },
```

As you can see the legend "Orion" has the highest `rating`, I would like to display in the embed for the highest rated legend. How can I do this?

Comment: The same way that you would if you actually had that data structure and it *didn't* come from JSON. You understand how to process lists and dictionaries? If that isn't enough help, then you need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: You showed us some code, but you didn't explain what happens when you try the code, or how that is different from what is supposed to happen. Please read [ask] and try to communicate clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a key to the `max` function to get the legend with the highest rating:

```
highest_elo = max(udata["legends"], key=lambda x: x["rating"])["legend_name_key"]
```

Comment: is there a way I can only print the "legend_name_key" of the highest rated legend?